# Team Foundation Server 2010 and SQL 2008 Express Advanced Services

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

As I can see here SQL Express has an edition with reporting services
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Does this mean I can use it to get all features for TFS 2010? Then what should I put when configuring TFS "Analysis Services" : where do I name this parameter when installing SQL Server EXPRESS Advanced ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Express 2008 R2 Doesn't has Analysis Services, so you end up missing out on a lot of the reports. (but not all)